# How can I install Net_LDAP3 for RoudCube?

Tags: php, ldap, roundcube

I have a mostly adequate result for availability of resources for RoundCube, but the check for requisite resources lists:

> Net_LDAP3:  NOT AVAILABLE(Recommended to install Net_LDAP3 from git.kolab.org; See https://git.kolab.org/diffusion/PNL)

I've cloned the Git repository, but what do I do to take a clone of the repository and install it so that RoundCube will see it?

This seems to be a basic question about administering PHP, but various searches have not turned up how to go from "cloned Git repository" to "have put it somewhere that RoundCube's resource check will see it."

The server is Debian 10, and an aptitude search for `php-net-ldap3` comes up dry.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian 10 Buster, the package [php-net-ldap3](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/php-net-ldap3) is only available in the backports repository.

The [backports documentation](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/#index2h2) has instructions to add the repo to your system:

- Add `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`)
- Run `apt update`
- Install the package: `apt install php-net-ldap3`